# Already creating inputs dynamically but unable to write on them. React Native - Redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I begun working with react-native and redux a month and a half ago with zero previous coding experience. I'm doing this because I really trust my idea and I want to craft it.

I'm very proud of what I've made but now I'm stuck since 2 weeks ago with a Iterator Component that I can't make it work as I want. **I’ve read everything about similar problems, I tried a lot of things and I still can't make it work. It's just a lack of experience and after all attempts I decided to ask for your help if it were possible.**

I'm crafting an app to allow people who loves to cook to sell their dishes in our platform. The main component allow the user to input basic info about the meal, like name, price an so on. Also the user has the chance to add some customization to their meal, for example: You could cook a pizza and probably you want to let your customers choose the kind of dough, like thin, traditional or bread kind of dough.

For this I’ve enabled a button which opens a modal with a dynamic form that create to objects in state and renders the basic two first options. Whenever you tap the button “Otra Opción” (add another in English) it adds another input.

The thing is that now I have working the functional component, the presentational one and some methods like componentWillMount that create the 2 first objects with their inputs and delete functionality to delete extra inputs **but** I can't write dynamically on those inputs… When I try it, I get this message:

> **Warning**: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.

Here is a gif that shows the app running in my simulator:
[image: Here is a gif that shows the app running in my simulator]

> As you can see in this Gif I also have a problem when I add more
> inputs, it is like previous inputs jumps when get re-render.

**What should I do to fix this?**

As you can see in the code below, all items has their unique key in the generator component. As an assumption, I thinks that the problem is how I'm capturing the ID of the component.

Here is the whole code of this modal component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { View, Modal, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';
import { Card, FormLabel, FormInput, Button } from 'react-native-elements';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import {
  agregarEleccion,
  addAnotherOption,
  deleteAnOption,
  findingInput,
  createOptions,
  addNewInput
 } from '/Users/felipefontsanguinetti/Documents/1000Deliverys/restoapp/src/state/actions';
class AEleccion extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.createOptions();
  }
  onCloseOptions() {
    this.props.agregarEleccion();
  }
  onDeleteOptionInput(id) {
    this.props.deleteAnOption(id);
  }
  findingInputHandler({ text, ids }) {
    console.log(capturing ${text} + ${ids});
    const id = ids;
    this.props.findingInput(text, id);
  }
  addNewInputHandler() {
    const nOfObjects = this.props.optionsToRender.length;
    console.log(hello, im the id: ${nOfObjects});
    this.props.addNewInput(nOfObjects);
  }
  render() {
    const { containterStyle, titleStyle, deleteButtonStyle, guideStyle } = styles;
    const DeleteButton = (props) => {
      if (props.id <= 1) {
        return (
          <Ionicons name="md-remove-circle" />
      );
      }
      return (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onDeleteOptionInput(props.id)}>
            <Ionicons name="md-remove-circle" />
          </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    };
    const FormLabelCMP = (props) => {
      return (
        <FormLabel key={props.id}>
          {props.children}
        </FormLabel>
      );
    };
    const OptionsInputPresentational = (props) => {
      const placeholderValue =
        (props.id == 0) ? 'Ej: Masa Fina'
          : (props.id == 1) ? 'Ej: Masa Tradicional'
            : (props.id == 2) ? 'Ej: Masa Pan'
              : 'Nueva Alternativa';
      return (
            <FormInput
              key={props.id}
              containerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 }}
              placeholder={placeholderValue}
              value={props.value}
              onChangeText={props.onChangeText}
            />
        );
    };
    const InputsToShow = this.props.optionsToRender.map((option, i) => {
      return (
        <View key={option.id} style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <View key={${i}delbutton} style={deleteButtonStyle}>
            <DeleteButton id={option.id} />
          </View>
          <View>
            <FormLabelCMP id={option.id}>{i + 1}º Alternativa</FormLabelCMP>
            <OptionsInputPresentational
              key={option.id}
              id={option.id}
              value={option.name}
              onChangeText={(text) => {
                let ids = option.id;
                this.findingInputHandler({ text, ids });
              }}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    });
    return (
      <Modal
      transparent
      animationType="fade"
      >
        <View style={containterStyle}>
          <ScrollView>
          <View style={{ marginTop: 15, alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onCloseOptions.bind(this)}>
              <Ionicons name="md-close-circle"  />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <Card containerStyle={{ borderRadius: 4, marginHorizontal: 10 }}>
            <View>
              <FormLabel labelStyle={guideStyle}>¿Qué darás a escoger?</FormLabel>
              <FormInput
                placeholder='Ej: Grosor de Masa'
                inputStyle={titleStyle}
                containerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 }}
              />
            </View>
            <Image
             style={{ height: 30, width: 260, alignSelf: 'center' }}
             source={require('/Users/felipefontsanguinetti/Documents/1000Deliverys/restoapp/src/resources/images/ModalDividerAEleccion.png')}
            />
            {InputsToShow}
            <View style={{ marginTop: 10, marginBottom: 15 }} flexDirection='row'>
              <Button
                onPress={this.addNewInputHandler.bind(this)}
                small
                leftIcon={{ name: 'add', type: 'materialicons', color: '#A1A84D' }}
                title='Otra Opción'
              />
              <Button
                small
                title='Guardar'
              />
            </View>
          </Card>
        </ScrollView>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
const styles = { Removed for brevity };
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
  optionsToRender: state.toggle.optionsToRender
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
   agregarEleccion,
   addAnotherOption,
   deleteAnOption,
   findingInput,
   createOptions,
   addNewInput })(AEleccion);
```

**Here the actions creators:**

```
export const createOptions = () => {
  return {
    type: CREATE_OPTIONS_OBJECT,
    payload: [{ id: '0', name: '' }, { id: '1', name: '' }]
  };
};

export const addNewInput = (nOfObjects) => {
  const newInputId = nOfObjects;
  return {
    type: ANOTHER_OPTION,
    id: newInputId
  };
};

export const deleteAnOption = (id) => {
  return {
    type: DELETE_OPTION,
    id
  };
};
'
export const findingInput = (text, id) => {
  console.log(`Escribiendo: ${text}, en inputId: ${id}`);
  return {
    type: DYNAMIC_HANDLER,
    id,
    payload: text
  };
};
```

**Here is the component reducer:**

```
import {
  TOGGLE_BUTTON,
  // ADD_SIDE,
  ADD_OPTIONS,
  ADD_CATEGORY,
  ADD_FOOD_NAME,
  ADD_INGREDIENT,
  ADD_PRICE,
  ANOTHER_OPTION,
  DELETE_OPTION,
  DYNAMIC_HANDLER,
  CREATE_OPTIONS_OBJECT
} from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  toggleButton: false,
  addOptions: false,
  addCategory: '',
  addFoodName: '',
  addIngredients: '',
  addPrice: '',
  //Add Options States
  optionTitle: '',
  optionsToRender: []
 };

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  console.log(action.type);
  switch (action.type) {
    case CREATE_OPTIONS_OBJECT:
      return { ...state, optionsToRender: action.payload };
    case TOGGLE_BUTTON:
      return { ...state, toggleButton: !state.toggleButton };
    case ADD_OPTIONS:
      return { ...state, addOptions: !state.addOptions, toggleButton: false };
    case ADD_CATEGORY:
      return { ...state, addCategory: action.payload };
    case ADD_FOOD_NAME:
      return { ...state, addFoodName: action.payload };
    case ADD_INGREDIENT:
      return { ...state, addIngredients: action.payload };
    case ADD_PRICE:
      return { ...state, addPrice: action.payload };
    //Add Options case
    case ANOTHER_OPTION:
      return {
        ...state, optionsToRender: [...state.optionsToRender, { id: action.id, name: '' }] };
    case DELETE_OPTION:
      return {
        ...state, optionsToRender: state.optionsToRender.filter((input) => { return action.id != input.id; })
       };
    case DYNAMIC_HANDLER:
    return { ...state,
      optionsToRender: state.optionsToRender.map(input => (input.id == action.id)
        ? [...state, { name: action.payload }]
        : state,
    ) };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

That's all. I hope you can help me. I’ve already made a lot of efforts to find the solution without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did try your advice and ir worked, the warning disapeared. Altough, this didn’t solve my problem (I thought if I fix that warning my component will write on the right input, but nope; I was missing something else) but helped me so much to finally find the root issue, finally.

Getting back to the intended behaviour of my component, Im trying to write to a input that has an unique key, but Im not able to get the “onChangeText” captured value of the input **right on the value of the input itself.**

While Im efectively capturing the value and sending it to the reducer, **im not expressing me correctly to it.** In the new object declaration Im missing something because Im only achieving to create a new object in the state instead on writting on the right input….

I tried in so many ways but I still stuck here.

The react component is the same above, but now here are the updated actions helpers, creator and reducers:

I create the input object:

```
componentWillMount() {
this.props.createOptions();
}
```

This helper call this action:

```
export const createOptions = () => {
 return {
  type: CREATE_OPTIONS_OBJECT,
  payload: [{ key: '0', name: '' }, { key: '1', name: '' }]
  };
 };
```

This action it's dispatched and received by this reducer:

```
case CREATE_OPTIONS_OBJECT:
  return { ...state, optionsToRender: action.payload };
```

So the new state is:

```
optionsToRender: [{ key: '0', name: '' }, { key: '1', name: '' }]
```

Once the Object it's created in the state. I trying to write on the name key, but Im unable to get it work...

**Im capturing the value this way in the flatlist as you suggested**:

```
<FlatList
          data={this.props.optionsToRender}
          renderItem={({ item }) => {
            return (
              <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                <View style={deleteButtonStyle}>
                  <DeleteButton id={item.key} />
                </View>

                <View>
                  <FormLabelCMP>{item.key}º Alternativa</FormLabelCMP>
                  <OptionsInputPresentational
                    id={item.key}
                    onChangeText={(text) => this.findingInputHandler({ text, item })}
                  />
                </View>
              </View>
            );
          }}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
        />
```

This component trigger this helper when user input:

```
findingInputHandler({ text, item }) {
const id = item.key;
console.log(`capturing ${text} + ${id}`);
this.props.findingInput(text, id);
}
```

This helper call this action:

```
export const findingInput = (text, id) => {
 console.log(`Escribiendo: ${text}, en inputId: ${id}`);
 return {
  type: DYNAMIC_HANDLER,
  id,
  payload: text
  };
 };
```

**And this is the part is not working.** Im creating a new object that only has name and Im replacing old state with this instead, but, how do I fix this? Dont know how to express myself to achieve this, yet :(

```
case DYNAMIC_HANDLER:
return {
  ...state,
  optionsToRender: [
    ...state.optionsToRender,
    state.optionsToRender.find(option => {
      return option.key == action.id ? { name: action.text } : option;
    })
```

] };

Thanks for your kindly help. It helped a lot, seriously. I learned a lot with it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of multiple keys inside same element, did you try implementing the same with a FlatList from 'react-native'? It has a built it keyextractor prop, and is recommended over the other methods. You can custom style your FlatList to anyway you want it. Hopefully this will solve the issue with unique keys.

About the re-rendering of elements when adding a new list in modal, unique key is what puts together the elements and is used by the renderer to understand which items are which and to manage them accordingly. Solving the issue with unique will most probably solve the re-rendering issue too.

This is not a definite answer for your particular issue, just my suggestion. Good luck and let me know the result.

Comment: Thanks you so much Hisham, I will definitely try it. I'll get back with the results as quick as I can. Have an awesome day!